# SQL Server and / or query

Tags: sql-server

The query below is still returning 0's in the `TC.ContractPartner` column can somebody explain why?

I've tried using '0' just in case the zero were text

```
select distinct tc.ID
, tc.[Contact Partner]
, so.BusinessPartnerNumber
, tc.[Actual Date From]
, SO.ServiceOrder
, SO.ServiceProduct
, so.SOCreatedOn

from AB.TradComplaints_Temp as TC

left Join main.Tbl_ServiceOrder as SO on SO.BusinessPartnerNumber = tc.[Contact Partner]

where tc.[Contact Partner] is not null
and tc.[Actual Date From] > so.SOCreatedOn
and  so.SOCreatedOn > (tc.[Actual Date From]-90)
and so.ServiceOrder is not null

or tc.[Contact Partner] <> 0
and tc.[Actual Date From] > so.SOCreatedOn
and  so.SOCreatedOn > (tc.[Actual Date From]-90)
and so.ServiceOrder is not null
order by tc.ID
```

Comment: Just use `where coalesce(tc.[Contact Partner], 0) <> 0` , but maybe there is a problem with your data.

Comment: In case Contact Partner not numeric, then you can also look to trim both sides white spaces, what is the datatype of this column?

Answer (score 1):

Change `or` to `and`?:

```
and so.ServiceOrder is not null
and tc.[Contact Partner] <> 0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want result when

```
so.ServiceOrder is not null or tc.[Contact Partner] <> 0
```

then group theses in braket

```
select distinct tc.ID
, tc.[Contact Partner]
, so.BusinessPartnerNumber
, tc.[Actual Date From]
, SO.ServiceOrder
, SO.ServiceProduct
, so.SOCreatedOn

from AB.TradComplaints_Temp as TC

left Join main.Tbl_ServiceOrder as SO on SO.BusinessPartnerNumber = tc.[Contact Partner]

where tc.[Contact Partner] is not null
and tc.[Actual Date From] > so.SOCreatedOn
and  so.SOCreatedOn > (tc.[Actual Date From]-90)
and (so.ServiceOrder is not null

or RTRIM(LTRIM(tc.[Contact Partner])) <> '0')
and tc.[Actual Date From] > so.SOCreatedOn
and  so.SOCreatedOn > (tc.[Actual Date From]-90)
and so.ServiceOrder is not null
order by tc.ID
```

Comment: I figured it was something to do with brackets but I still can't get it working. 'code' where (tc.[Contact Partner] is not null 
or tc.[Contact Partner] <> 0)
and tc.[Actual Date From] > so.SOCreatedOn
and  so.SOCreatedOn > (tc.[Actual Date From]-90)
and so.ServiceOrder is not nul 'code'

Comment: when so.ServiceOrder is not null then it will also give "Contact Partner" with 0. Then you need to convert  or into "AND" to exclude both. what is your requirement?